# How to properly program a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've been having some fun reading about windows services on MSDN, but i'm having some trouble grasping some of the information.

I have created a windows service following the steps at [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and i noticed that they ommitted that one of the automatically generated sections (namely, the main section in program.cs) starts a collection of services. I'm having trouble understanding how will a service actually run, or more correctly, how do i correctly program a service to do what i want. The automatically generated service.cs only has a constructor, an an OnStart and OnStop event methods. Should i program the bulk of my code on the OnStart method, or is there a similar Main section to services?

Another question i have is regarding the deployment of services. At the page i mentioned, they referenced another page that has me use installutil on the VS developer console. How can i make an automatic installer for the service, in case the target platform doesn't have the developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make an automatic installer for the service, in case the target platform doesn't have the developer console?

You have to add a `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` to install your service on a remote machine. This should even work if the target machine doesn't have the developer console available.

> I'm having trouble understanding how will a service actually run, or
>   more correctly, how do i correctly program a service to do what i
>   want.

That's actually a lot simpler than you might initially think. Your service will run the same as it would if it was a normal process. If you have a console application that opens a port and listens for traffic, then that would still work pretty much in the same way when you turn it into a service.

What does change, however, is how your service is started. After you have installed your service properly, you can start it like this:

```
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new YourServerClass()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

`YourServerClass` should inherit `ServiceBase`, which will allow you to use the `OnStart`, `OnStop` methods. In those methods you specify how your service is started, and what should be done (in terms of cleanup etc.) when your service is stopped.

If all went well, and you have the installetr and the actual service in the project, you should be able to [install it as a service through the use of PowerShell](http://devtxt.com/blog/install-a-windows-service-using-powershell), after which you can just start, stop and restart it from the Services window as you would with any other service.

Comment: So the OnStart method will be called by ServiceBase.Run()... In that case, I can use the OnStart to perform the YourServerClass operations, right? I'm just a bit confused as to how the program should run, since you also mentioned that the OnStart should "specify how the service is started", and i know that conventions go a long way to make it easier to understand code.

Comment: Yes, in an implementation I did a while ago I start my WCF service from the `OnStart` method, and close it in the `OnStop`. What I meant by specifying how the service is started is how the actual functionality that your service will provide is started, which in my case was a WCF service.

Answer (score 2):

A service is no more than a (most of the time) console program. So, yes, the OnStart method is the entry point for your service, just like the Main method. If your service has to be executed periodically, you have to manage the loop part. The OnStop method is called whenever the user manually stops the service or when the system does.
The reason there is a ServiceBase array launched in the Main Program method, is that you can have multiple service classes and launch them in parallel.
You have to know that the content of the Main method can only be executed by the system in the context of an installed service. You cannot debug this way. You have to do it using a classic "console app". I personally use a trick to debug a service in VisualStudio more easily:

- Let say we have an ImportService class that do our processing. We will use DEBUG compiler constant and create a DebugStart() method that will start processing (OnStart method is protected)

  ```
  #if DEBUG
     public void DebugStart()
     {
        // Call you processing method
     }
  #endif
  ```
- Now let's edit our Main() Program method the same way to start our processing instead of the ServiceBase.Run method when debugging:

  ```
  #if DEBUG
      ImportService service = new ImportService();
      service.DebugStart();
  #else
      ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun =
      { 
          new ImportService() 
      };
      ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
  #endif
  ```

This way, when running your project in debug mode it will launch the service as a standard console program.
The installutil command is a windows command used to install a service program. To install your service, you have multiple solutions, depending on your installer:

- Using InstallShield. Since Visual Studio 2013 (or maybe 2012?), InstallShield Lite Edition is standardly included in place of former Windows Installer. You have to activate and install it though (Create a new project of Other types>Configuration and deployment>Activate InstallShield Limited Edition). You can install windows services with it in the form of an installer
- Making a simple .bat file that will run the installutil command on the client machine.
- Using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) which is very complete but also more complex but allows you to do anything during installation.